# R: Can exists() function be used within mutate() (dplyr package)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a new variable in case it doesn't exist. If it exists nothing has to be changed, but if it doesn't I want to make this variable and give it NA values. I tried to do this with mutate function of the dplyr package, but I only get NA's as a result.

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(47, 801, 660), var2 = c(11, 
17, 11)), .Names = c("var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I check the existence of var2.

```
df <- mutate(df, var2 = ifelse(exists('var2')==TRUE,var2,NA))
```

the result is:

```
  var1 var2
1   47   NA
2  801   NA
3  660   NA
```

but, the result SHOULD be (because nothing had to be changed:

```
  var1 var2
1   47   11
2  801   17
3  660   11
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Can it even be done with exists()? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you have quotations mark on `var1`, try `!is.na(var1)` instead of `exists('var1')`, also is var2 just supposed to be var1?

Comment: I don't need to check on na's, but on the existence of variables. I will try this with !exists(var1).

Comment: I edited the question and the mutate function, I hope the problem is more clear now.

Comment: What about sth like `mutate(df, var2 = if ("var1" %in% names(df)) var1 else NA)`?

Comment: thanks for the hint!!! this seems to work: df <- mutate(df, var2 = ifelse("var2" %in% names(df), var2,NA))

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use

```
mutate(df, var2 = if (exists('var2', where = df)) var2 else NA)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Just a note, because I get confused when piping things around - this is equivalent to: `df %>% foo() %>% mutate(var2 = if (exists('var2', where=.)) var2 else NA) %>% bar()`

Comment: @dwanderson Apart from `foo()` and `bar()`, both commands are identical.